# htaccess redirect root?var=abc to file.php?var=abc

Tags: .htaccess

I'm having trouble redirecting URLs like `site.com/?var=abc` to `site.com/file.php?var=abc`.

I tried a lot of redirect codes but none worked. I installed Wordpress in the root directory of the site and I'm trying to move the old content based on GET variables to file.php.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To redirect every empty url to `file.php`, here is what you need to write in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ file.php [R=301,QSA,L]
```

`[QSA]` tag will append your query string (`?var=abc`) to the new url.

---

To redirect the **exact** format `/?var=abc`, you'll need to use `%{QUERY_STRING}`:

```
# Check for query string, must be exactly "?var=abc"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^var=abc$
# Check for url, must be "/" or ""
RewriteRule ^/?$ file.php [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to redirect every URL. Only those that match exactly the format: site.com/?var=abc. I have another website now in the root domain that uses permalinks. I need to redirect the old website to file.php.

Comment: Not working. I've tried exactly like this: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^var=abc$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /file.php [R=301,QSA,L]

Comment: You may have something interfering. Is there anything else in your htaccess? And what does "not working" means? What happens?

Comment: I've removed the redirects from wordpress. Nothing happens, links with var=abc don't redirect to file.php, the Home page of wordpress site opens, no error.

Comment: Please note that 301 redirections are strongly cached. You probably need to clear your browser cache to get the new htaccess taken in account.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding (.*)$ after the first variable (var), there were many other parameters in the link.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^var=(.*)$

RewriteRule ^/?$ /file.php$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```